# Android design : background long running service or AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, boot

I am building an app which will monitor the battery state, wifi connection and location data at regular intervals and will write the results in a file (and later send them off to a server). On installing the app monitoring should be disabled - but the user enabling it should survive a reboot. After a lot of reading I have realized that I have basically 2 options :

- Subclass `Service` and fire it off from my activity. Set it on foreground, STICKY and what not and hope that it is not killed by android - and take care if android recreates it (actually there should be 3 services so syncing between them could be messy). Start a thread in the service (no need for Executors I guess) and have it `Thread.sleep(REGULAR_INTERVAL)`. Wake up, collect the data write them to a file. Broadcast the collected info and display it on my activity if it happens to be running (which will have registered a Broadcast Receiver). Rinse and repeat `while(true)`. Have  a way to interrupt this
- Have my activity register a PendingIntent with AlarmManager - which will run every REGULAR_INTERVAL. I haven't looked into the technical details of this approach so much - but I hope I will be able to make this PendingIntent create and run an IntentService (this seems the way to go - having the Thread machinery for free as well as shutting down on its own). Some skeleton code for this approach would be welcome.

I think I have to register a boot receiver in both cases to check the Shared Preferences (have already done this) and in case 1 start the service(s) while in case 2 register a Receiver for the alarm event and set the alarm manager up - that is the part I need some skeleton code.

So - before I start building this - which would be the preferred approach ?

In recap - the app should monitor some phone properties and write them to a file till the user chooses to shut it off.

Comment: Your users will probably kill you if you keep a `Service` alive continuously draining their phone's battery just to gather dome data at certain time intervals. Use the second approach, with an `IntentService` with additional WakeLocks if needed(have a look at CommonsWare's `WakefullIntentService`).

Comment: @Luksprog : thanks - would I need locks ? in the broadcast receiver which would receive the alarm (still looking into how exactly should this be implemented) ?

Comment: Why the negative vote ?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question but someone else didn't liked it. Don't be too stressed about that.

Comment: @Luksprog: Yes no prob - I didn't think it was you :D - I hate downvotes for no reason - and anyway it's not a bad question or anything - duh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> while in case 2 register a Receiver for the alarm event and set the alarm manager up

Your receiver will already be registered via the manifest.

> which would be the preferred approach ?

`AlarmManager`, assuming `REGULAR_INTERVAL` is typically decently long (e.g., over a few minutes). Ideally, that interval is user-configurable.

If you intend to do this even when the device is otherwise asleep, your option #1 simply will not work, unless you keep a `WakeLock` on all the time, which will cause your users to want to shoot you in the face with a shotgun.

> Some skeleton code for this approach would be welcome.

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Scheduled) demonstrating the use of `AlarmManager` for non-`_WAKEUP` alarms (i.e., you only need these events to occur while the device is already awake for other reasons).

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful) demonstrating the use of `AlarmManager` for `_WAKEUP` alarms, using [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). `WakefulIntentService` (or something like it) is necessary because `AlarmManager` does not keep the device awake very long (just long enough for `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver`), and so you need to take additional steps to keep the device awake long enough for you to do your work. *Theoretically*, your work might be quick enough to do just in `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver`, avoiding the need to mess with the `WakefulIntentService`. However, you will be doing disk I/O each of these times, which ideally should not be done on the main application thread, where `onReceive()` is called. And, when you go to upload your data, you may well need a `WakefulIntentService` then, anyway, if you are looking to do that in the background as well.

Comment: Thanks - why register the BroadcastReceiver in the manifest (not the Boot one - this must be there) ? Wouldn't this mean that it will be registered all the time - resulting in some overhead ? While BootReceiver -> `is monitoring enabled ? (register a receiver for the alarm; set up the alarm) : return` seems more economical. Also the AlarmReceiver will run in my main UI thread ? This would be the case when my activity (which just displays data collected and allows enabling/disabling monitoring) is up - no ? Otherwise there would be no UI thread (or it would not make a difference)- am I wrong ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: "why register the BroadcastReceiver in the manifest" -- otherwise, you need to keep a component (e.g., Service) around all the time, which is the point behind switching to `AlarmManager`. You do *not* want to be taking up memory all of the time. "Wouldn't this mean that it will be registered all the time - resulting in some overhead ?" -- it will only be used by your `AlarmManager`. "Also the AlarmReceiver will run in my main UI thread ?" -- `onReceive()` of `BroadcastReceiver` is called on the main application thread.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: "Otherwise there would be no UI thread" -- there is always a "UI thread", more accurately referred to as the "main application thread". If you spend too much time on the main application thread, even from `onReceive()`, Android will terminate your operation.

Comment: Ok - I have to read up on BRs - I thought that if I registered the receiver in the boot receiver - or in my app whenever the user enabled monitoring I would be fine. Will have a look at the code posted and come back for more - as there are many small details escaping me :)

Comment: @CommonsWare. Any idea how does  app like whatsapp, fb works so smoothly - almost real time and with not much battery drain. Can you recommend any sample  application for that. I love your books and blogs and it will be great if you can write a blog post on it. I found many to be confused (including me) and saw all your answers on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

use second option , and should use intentService + AlarmManager see this example http://www.dotkam.com/2011/01/10/android-prefer-alarms-and-intent-receivers-to-services/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the length of the recurring task you can choose one of several approaches. This question discusses them - [Scheduling recurring task in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376470/scheduling-recurring-task-in-android/14980699)

Using an AlarmManager is convenient when task sleep times are 15 minutes or longer. The pattern is well known.

Comment: @CommonsWare : I have similar situation to perform some task(GPS Positioning) on interval of 1 min. I am using Handler for that in my Main Activity how will it affect my application